# My PHP Mailer Code is giving a HTTP 500 error

Tags: php, phpmailer, contact-form

I have compiled a detailed application form for a website which uses normal text boxes, drop down option boxes, Calendar for dates, check boxes and attachment. I got the form to email beautifully using just normal PHP but i got stuck when dealing with the attachment section. I then learnt its best to use PHP Mailer so i have re done the PHP for this but getting the dreaded HTTP 500 error. Please could someone check out my code to see where i am going wrong please. Thank you very much in advance.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'href="/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php"';
require 'href="/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php"';

$message = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
$string = trim($string);
$string = stripslashes($string);
$string = htmlspecialchars($string);
return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$path = 'href="/upload/"' . $_FILES["attachment"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $path);
$message = '
<h3 align="center">Application Details</h3>
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td width="30%">First Name</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["first_name"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Last Name</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["last_name"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Email Address</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["email"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Phone Number</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["phone_number"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Position</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["position"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">WhatsApp Number</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["whatsapp_no"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Yacht Name</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["yacht_name"].'</td>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Yacht Type</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["yacht_type"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Yacht Size</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["yacht_size"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Cruising Type</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["cruising_type"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Yacht Location</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["yacht_location"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Yacht Itinenary</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["yacht_itinenary"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Work Posistion</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["work_position"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Work Type</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["work_type"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Start Date</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["start_date"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Finish Date</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["finishing_date"].'</td>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Visa Required</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["visa_req"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Qualifications Required</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["qual_req"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Job Description</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["job_desc"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Shared Cabin</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["shared_cabin"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Understood Terms</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["terms"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30%">Confidental</td>
<td width="70%">'.$_POST["confidential"].'</td>
</tr>
</table>
';
if (isset($_POST['shared_cabin'])){
$_POST['shared_cabin']; // Displays value of checked checkbox.
} 
if (isset($_POST['terms'])){
$_POST['terms']; // Displays value of checked checkbox.
} 
if (isset($_POST['confidential'])){
$_POST['confidential']; // Displays value of checked checkbox.
}   

require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
$mail->From = $_POST["email_from"];     //Sets the From email address for 
the message
$mail->FromName = $_POST["first_name"]["last_name"];    //Sets the From 
name of the message
$mail->AddAddress('timmy2872@gmail.com');  //Adds a "To" address
$mail->WordWrap = 50;       //Sets word wrapping on the body of the 
message to a given number of characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);       //Sets message type to HTML
$mail->AddAttachment($path);     //Adds an attachment from a path on the 
filesystem
$mail->Subject = 'Employer Application Form details';    //Sets the 
Subject of the message
$mail->Body = $message;       //An HTML or plain text message body
if($mail->Send())        //Send an Email. Return true on success or false 
on error
{
$message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Application Successfully 
Submitted</div>';
unlink($path);
}
else
{
$message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">There is an Error</div>';
}
}

?>
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: And as far as I know you have to configure phpmailer too, so set host, username, password, etc. But I could be wrong about that, just never saw it without any kind of config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fixed and working like a dream now. 
Problem was, the site i,m working on is in a "Temp" folder as not to upset the old site. I had the PHPMailer and Upload folder in the sub directory and not the main directory of the server so this is how it needed to be -

```
require "/home/awolpm/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";
require "/home/awolpm/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
```

Also this line was not needed -

```
 require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
```

The Upload folder needed to be -

```
$path = '/home/awolpm/upload/"' . $FILES["attachment"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $path);
```

Certainly made me scratch my head for a while!

One last thing to do for it - make a pop up modal box on success of sending and return a confirmation email to the sender.